# Should you fork your own Project and submit pull request?

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request, git-fork

Hi I started a project on github with other people contributing, should I fork my own project and do updates via pull request. I've only been pushing changes to branches so far, and I am wondering if that is a bad practice.

What is the Git etiquette here?

Comment: You're free to do whatever you want. Including creating pull requests from a branch of your own repo. No need to fork to use PRs.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely not a bad practice, it's a completely normal way to use git.

As I see, the usual approach is to use `master` as a relatively stable branch, which can be built anytime. You implement new features in other branches, *feature branches*, then merge this into `master`. GitHub extends this way of doing things with pull requests, which are usually merged into `master`, just like feature branches of your own.

But the bottom line is: the system is flexible, and there is no single way of doing things, so you can choose whatever is comfortable for you, and your contributors.

Answer (score 4):

Of cause you can do that. But there is a more efficient way to that.

Since you have permission to push on your repo, so you can create a branch from which you are working and do your works on the new created branch. After finish working, push it to github and create a PR to merge this branch into your contribute branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest keeping on using branches for the work you do. Keeps stuff stable but I wouldn't bother forking my own repository.

Maybe adding some contributors to your repository so that you can have more people help with reviewing the Pull Requests if your project gets big enough.