# How to create a Pull Request on my own upstream repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a Git repo that I use as a "starter point" for multiple projects I work on. They all share some code but are independent and different, so I want to manage them as separate repos (instead of different branches on the same repo).

That being said, I do want to have the option to update the "base repo" from time to time (if, for example, I find a bug in "base repo" while working some downstream repo). Following [this guide](https://deanmalone.net/post/how-to-fork-your-own-repo-on-github/), I cloned my "base repo" to a new project and set the original as an upstream repo.

Still, I'm unable to create a pull request on the upstream ("base") repo, and am starting to think this isn't possible at all when working on my own repos.

Is it possible to create a PR on an upstream repo that I control?
Alternatively, what's the "good practice" for managing multiple projects (some private, some public) that originate from a shared "common ancestor"?

I should mention that I've found these two posts with a similar use-case ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110207/git-creating-pull-request-without-forking), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129755/should-you-fork-your-own-project-and-submit-pull-request)), but answers there are contradicting and don't work in my case.

Comment: I don't get what's preventing you to just clone your base repo, create a branch, push it to the base repo, open a PR? You don't need to fork the base repo if you own it.

Comment: I don't get what's preventing me from doing that either, @GaëlJ , other than the fact that GitHub doesn't let me do it. I cloned "base repo" to "new repo", pushed a revision to "new repo" and yet I can't open a PR on "base repo". I tried opening a PR through GitHub, both on "base repo" and on "new repo" but am unable to compare branches between the two repos

Comment: I meant you don't even need a "new repo" at all.

Comment: ahh, because it's a different project and I want this logical separation

Comment: @GaëlJ I honestly don't understand what you're proposing. I *did* clone my own original repo (hence "new repo" is the name of the clone) and created a branch on said "new repo"; but I can't create a PR from my cloned "new repo" onto the original repo.  
This is the point I was trying to make in this post.

Comment: "cloning" is the action of retrieving a repo on your machine. I think you mean "copy" or "fork" when you say "clone". I just mean use the original repo.